# Choice based on other turtles' variables

Tags: netlogo

I'm stuck with my ABM. The situation is very simple: there are some turtles, producers, and others, choosers. Producers produce a product with a certain quality, choosers choose based on perceived quality.

Perceived quality is a function "quality-of-product-of-producers **-** beta-of-chooser", where beta is an individual adaptive variable. All these variables are turtles-own, and they all own them (at each round roles are switched).

I'd like the following to happen: quality-of-product is a producers' variable, beta is a choosers' variable. How to code the operation?

I've tried the following things:

```
ask turtles with [group = "producers"] [
    set perceived-product-quality ((product-quality - beta))
  ]
```

However, like beta is producers' one (incorrect, should be choosers).

Then I've tried this:

```
ask turtles with [group = "choosers"] [
    let quality [product-quality] of turtles with [ group = "producers" ]
    set perceived-product-quality quality - beta
  ]
```

However, it doesn't work, runtime error: “expected input to be a number but got the list“.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact use case is, if you're trying to query the mean product quality / beta from all producers and choosers, but the general answer I *think* is that you need to be explicit with which turtles you're actually trying to pull values from. When you use `ask`, the agent that you are `ask`ing to do something will default to using its own variables if it owns them. So, if you are needing to stick with `turtles-own` variables rather than making breeds and breed-specific variables, you'll need to explicitly state which turtle you're trying to reference. Here is a toy example that has choosers pick the product quality of whatever producer is nearest for use in the formula:

```
turtles-own [ group product-quality beta perceived-product-quality]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 10 patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set group one-of [ "producers" "choosers" ]
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    ifelse group = "producers" [
      set product-quality random 500 + 500
      set beta random 200 + 100
      set color red
    ] [
      set product-quality random 50 + 50
      set beta random 20 + 10
      set color blue
    ] 
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to set-perceived
  let current-producers turtles with [ group = "producers" ]
  let current-choosers turtles with [ group = "choosers" ]
  ask current-choosers [
    ; Pick the closest producer
    let closest-producer min-one-of current-producers [ distance myself ] 
    
    ; Pull the product quality of that closest producer
    let closest-product-quality [ product-quality ] of closest-producer
   
    ; Set MY perceived product quality to be closest-product-quality - MY beta
    set perceived-product-quality closest-product-quality - beta
    show ( 
      word "I used the turtle " closest-producer 
      " to determine my perceived product quality of: " perceived-product-quality 
    )
  ]
end
```

**Edit:**

Comment update:

> I'd like the following to happen: choosers do the operation “perceived-product-quality - beta“ for all turtles in the Moore neighbour. After doing this, they are going to choose the product with highest value of perceived-product-quality.

In this version, there is a `to-report` procedure that reports the perceived product quality from the perspective of `from-who`. This can then be used with `max-one-of` to return the turtle with the highest perceived value.

```
turtles-own [ group product-quality beta perceived-product-quality]

to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 5 0 5
  set-patch-size 40
  ask patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set group one-of [ "producers" "choosers" ]
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [
    ifelse group = "producers" [
      set product-quality random 500 + 500
      set beta random 200 + 100
      set color red
    ] [
      set product-quality random 50 + 50
      set beta random 20 + 10
      set color blue
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to choose-best-moore
  let current-choosers turtles with [ group = "choosers" ]
  ask current-choosers [
    let current-producers ( turtles-on neighbors ) with [ group = "producers" ]
    ifelse any? current-producers [
      let turtle-with-highest-perceived max-one-of current-producers [ perceived-target-value myself ]
      let real-product-quality [product-quality] of turtle-with-highest-perceived
      let false-product-quality [ perceived-target-value myself ] of turtle-with-highest-perceived 
      show ( word "I surveyed " count current-producers " and found that " turtle-with-highest-perceived 
        " had the best product quality (real: " real-product-quality ", perceived: " false-product-quality ")" )
    ] [
      show "I found no producers in my neighboring cells"
    ]
  ]
end

to-report perceived-target-value [ from-who ] 
  let target-product-quality product-quality
  let target-perceived-quality ( target-product-quality - [beta] of from-who )
  report target-perceived-quality
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I'm getting closer to the desired code with your suggestion. However, I still have a problem. I'll try to be more specific.

Your code succeeds in doing the operation “perceived-product-quality -beta“ for one specific targeted turtle (closest-product-quality). 

I'd like the following to happen: choosers do the operation “perceived-product-quality - beta“ for all turtles in the Moore neighbour. After doing this, they are going to choose the product with highest value of perceived-product-quality. Do you think this is feasible?

Comment: @garzi - a) most things are feasible if you can dream them b) I have updated the answer to include one way of doing what you describe, though there are many- the *best*  way will depend on your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, Luke! You've been incredibly helpful :)

Comment: @garzi - glad to be of service, happy coding!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I am making the model a bit more complex. I have some problems with this bit of code. 
I introduced two kinds of producers: t-producers and f-producers. Choosers always choose on the basis of “perceived-product-quality”. However, for t-producers there is no “minus beta”. For f-producers it goes exactcly how you coded it (“target-product-quality - [beta] of from-who ”). 

I have tried several versions, but no one seems right. How can I make choosers select the product with highest perceived quality, but in one case there is “- beta” and not in the other?

Comment: @garzi - Sorry for the delay- did you sort this out? I'm not sure if I understand, but I would think you could simply make a different `to-report` procedure specific to those with no beta parameter (or, modify the original to-report procedure such that it can address the case you describe). If that misses the mark, it might be best to make a new question to a) explicitly lay out a working example, b) make the question / answer pair more accessible to new users, and c) potentially get you a quicker answer!

Comment: @ Luke C I opened a new question! I figured out it was better than updating this one. 
Yes, you understood correctly. My goal would be to modify the original `to-report` --that you helped me code-- to account for this difference between t-producers and f-producers. So, choosers would select the turtle with the highest value of perceived quality after having subtracted beta from one type of agents (f-producers). 
The bit of code you helped me with works very nicely, so I am having troubles to change it (I always make it worse).